# Loading fragment cause covering view with higher z-index in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a base activity with header and footer and main frame with to child for loading two fragment! my main frame is the view with lowest z-index and should go to backward but when fragment loaded cover part of header and footer with higher z-index!can see in this image:

what happening when fragments load:
[image: when fragment cover my activity views]

and without loading fragment:
[image]

my base activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/layout_base_container"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

//mani frame for loading fragments
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/base_header"
    android:layout_above="@+id/base_footer"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    //first fragment 
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layout_cart_frame"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
    //second fragment
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:id="@+id/layout_foods_frame"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/base_header"
   ....>

//some view here

</LinearLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/base_header_shadow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/base_header"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/base_footer_shadow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow_upside"
    android:layout_above="@+id/base_footer"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/base_footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


//upper image that cover by fragments
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo_image"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    app:civ_fill_color="@color/colorSecondary"
    app:civ_border_width="13dp"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />


//left bottom circle button
<Button
    android:layout_width="135dp"
    android:layout_height="135dp"
    android:text="ثبت نهایی"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_button_stroke"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-25dp"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:textAllCaps="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i suddenly want a pizza.

Comment: First of all, consider not having inflated elements on top of each other. This is really bad for android performance.

Comment: @TiagoDávila ok but how can i solve the problem?